# Is there a systematic study of the effects of choosing the wrong distribution to model data?

Tags: distributions, error

I would like to know if there is any study showing what are the effects
of modelling data using the wrong probability distribution.
Any reference to papers or books explaining it (possibly for a novice/intermediate audience) is fine.

Comment: This is very broad....Perhaps too broad. Can you narrow it down? What sort of models? What sort of distributions?

Comment: actually I wanted really broad.. but anyway what I am most interested is in the effects of using normal distributions to model data that follows other distributions...

Comment: The effect will differ substantially depending on the nature of the other distribution, so this seems too broad to me too.